# Using manual registration in a gerrit plugin

Tags: guice, gerrit

When writing gerrit plugins you have the choice to either use AutoRegistration (using the `@Listen` and `@Export` annotations) or to use manual registration by defining `<GerritModule>`, `<Gerrit-SshModule>` and/or `<Gerrit-HttpModule>` in the `pom.xml`.

Auto-Registration is shown in [this](http://de.slideshare.net/lucamilanesio/gerrit-how-to-cook-a-plugin-in-only-10-mins) slide set, but documentation on how to use manual registration is sparse. So how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we want to convert the `commit-message-length-validator` plugin to manual registration. A stripped down version of it looks like this:

```
@Listen
@Singleton
public class CommitMessageLengthValidation implements CommitValidationListener {
  public List<CommitValidationMessage> onCommitReceived(CommitReceivedEvent receiveEvent)
      throws CommitValidationException {
    // do something
  }
}
```

The `<GerritModule>` entry in the `pom.xml` or buck build script has to point to a Guice module, so we have to create one.

```
class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
     // this does manual registration of CommitMessageLengthValidation
     DynamicSet.bind(binder(), CommitValidationListener.class)
         .to(CommitMessageLengthValidation.class);
  }
}
```

Replacing a `@Export` annotation is slightly more complicated. For a SSH command create a Guice module by extending `PluginCommandModule`:

```
class MySshModule extends PluginCommandModule {
  @Override
  protected void configureCommands() {
    command(PrintHelloWorldCommand.class);
    alias("say-hello", PrintHelloWorldCommand.class);
  }
}
```

For HTTP Servlets use a `ServletModule`:

```
public class Git2MksHttpModule extends ServletModule {
  @Override
  protected void configureServlets() {
    serve("/servertime").with(ServerTime.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you be willing to add this information in the Gerrit documentation?

Comment: If you tell me how and where, I guess I could do that.

Comment: Great, thanks.   If you haven't worked with Gerrit before, have a look at the contributor documentation [1].  Once you've cloned the repository you'll find the documentation relevant for plugins at Documentation/dev-plugins.txt

[1] http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.6/dev-contributing.html